# upload file with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, directory

I´m trying upload one file to `storage/app` with laravel for this, i´m checking that my folder exist:

```
if(isset($request->file_job)){
            $pathFolder = storage_path('app/contratos/'.$tarea->contratoTrey->serie->SERIE.'-'.$tarea->contratoTrey->N_CONTRATO.'/tareas/T-'.$tarea->ntarea);
           
            if(!\File::exists($pathFolder)) {
                \File::makeDirectory($pathFolder, 0755, true, true);
            }


            $filePath = 'app/contratos/'.$tarea->contratoTrey->serie->SERIE.'-'.$tarea->contratoTrey->N_CONTRATO.'/tareas/T-'.$tarea->ntarea;
            \Storage::disk('local')->put($filePath, $request->file_job);
        }
```

if not exist i´m building my structure folder and put my file in this folder.

My problem it´s in my DB i´m insert my file name with `getClientOriginalName()` but in this route

```
'app/contratos/'.$tarea->contratoTrey->serie->SERIE
```

my app was builded a file, not directory and in this directory my file with his original name...

i don´t know that i´m doing wrong.. i trayed creating a new variable with this name and save... same error or problem...

**UPDATE**

```
\Storage::disk('local')->putFileAs($filePath, $request->file_job, ($request->file_job)->getClientOriginalName());
```

Thanks for readme and help me. Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue might be that you are using put instead of putFileAs. You can find the documentation in https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#specifying-a-file-name so, instead of:

```
\Storage::disk('local')->put($filePath, $request->file_job);
```

You should:

```
\Storage::disk('local')->putFileAs($filePath, $request->file_job, ($request->file_job)->getClientOriginalName());
```