# Cannot move image/files temp to public directory Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-filesystem

I am trying to upload an image in Laravel. Getting the following error:

```
"message": "Could not move the file \"C:\\xampp\\tmp\\php84AA.tmp\" to \"F:\\bvend\\bvend-web\\public\\uploads/products\\bvend-product-1666274539.jpg\" (move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move &quot;C:\\xampp\\tmp\\php84AA.tmp&quot; to &quot;F:\\bvend\\bvend-web\\public\\uploads/products\\bvend-product-1666274539.jpg&quot;).",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\File\\Exception\\FileException",
    "file": "F:\\bvend\\bvend-web\\vendor\\symfony\\http-foundation\\File\\UploadedFile.php",
    "line": 177,
    "trace": [ .... ]
```

My code is given below:

```
public function uploadImage($image, $image_path)
{
    $path = config('global.' . $image_path . '_image_path');

    file_exists($image) && unlink($image);

    $image_name = 'bvend-' . $image_path . '-' . time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $image->move($path, $image_name); // $path: public_path('uploads/products')
    return $image_name;
}
```

I understand its a simple issue but still no clue where it causing issue.

Comment: In Laravel you should not upload to the poblic folder, but to the storage folder (`storage_path()`). and run `php artisan storage link` to create a symlink in public.

Comment: @GertB. thanks now the error is gone but the image file not moving to the destination folder. I checked the path which is correct.

Comment: [upload file with laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71694681/upload-file-with-laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Edit

> @WahidulAlam Please, try removing `file_exists($image) && unlink($image);`
> – steven7mwesigwa - https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/130904221?noredirect=1
>
> @WahidulAlam You're essentially **deleting** the temporary file/image before its copied or moved.
> – steven7mwesigwa - https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/130904261?noredirect=1
>
> ah this is the catch !! thanks a lot.
> – Wahidul Alam - https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/130904399?noredirect=1

---

[Specifying A File Name](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#specifying-a-file-name)

> If you do not want a filename to be automatically assigned to your
> stored file, you may use the `storeAs` method, which receives the
> path, the filename, and the (optional) disk as its arguments:

> ```php
> $path = $request->file('avatar')->storeAs(
>     'avatars', $request->user()->id
> );
> ```

> You may also use the `putFileAs` method on the `Storage` facade, which
> will perform the same file storage operation as the example above:

> ```php
> $path = Storage::putFileAs(
>     'avatars', $request->file('avatar'), $request->user()->id
> );
> ```

##### Solution

```php
public function uploadImage(\Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile $image, $image_path)
{
    return $image->storePubliclyAs(
    config('global.' . $image_path . '_image_path'),
    'bvend-' . $image_path . '-' . time(),
    ["disk" => "public"]
);
}
```

##### Addendum

Don't forget to create a symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`. I.e:
`php artisan storage:link`.

[The Public Disk](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#the-public-disk)

> Once a file has been stored and the symbolic link has been created,
> you can create a URL to the files using the `asset` helper:

> ```php
> echo asset('storage/file.txt');
> ```

##### In Summary

```php
$savedPath = $request->file("***REQUEST-INPUT-IMAGE-NAME-HERE***")->storePubliclyAs(
    "***IMAGE-PATH-HERE***",
    "***CUSTOM-FILENAME-HERE***",
    ["disk" => "public"]
);
```

Comment: thanks @steven. But it shows exception
: 
"ValueError"
file
: 
"F:\\bvend\\bvend-web\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Filesystem\\FilesystemAdapter.php"
line
: 
396
message
: 
"Path cannot be empty"

Comment: @WahidulAlam Please try my edited solution.

Comment: thanks for your prompt help. but unfortunately its still shows same error.

Comment: @WahidulAlam You may find this helpful ["Path cannot be empty" laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70093647/path-cannot-be-empty-laravel)

Comment: please watch: https://screenrec.com/share/qLxW3CpDSF

Comment: @WahidulAlam Please, try removing `file_exists($image) && unlink($image);`

Comment: @WahidulAlam You're essentially **deleting** the temporary file/image before its copied or moved.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this methodology in Laravel 9.

try this:

```
public function uploadImage($image, $image_path)
            {
               // $path = config('global.' . $image_path . '_image_path');

                file_exists($image) && unlink($image);

                $image_name = 'bvend-' . $image_path . '-' . time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

                //$image->move($path, $image_name); // $path: public_path('uploads/products')
                $image->move(public_path('/images'), $image_name);
                return $image_name;
            }
```